# Why I can't send .load() Jquery with a form to the loaded page?

Tags: jquery, html, post, flask, load

The next page loaded fine, without any error message, but does not show the posted data for `{{nomeUsuario}}` in jinja

py:

```
@app.route('/Items', methods=['POST','GET'])
def Items():
    return render_template("Items.html")
```

Main.html:

```
<button type="submit" id="formbtn" name="nomeUsuario" value="{{ x[1] }}">Carregar</button>

<script>
    var nomeUsuario = $(this).val();
    $('#formbtn').on('click',function(){
        $("#menu").load('Items',nomeUsuario);
    }); 
</script>
```

Items.html:

```
<h1>{{ nomeUsuario }}</h1>
```

Comment: `this` is the `window` in the context shown. It has no `val()`. Also need a key/value pair sent to server

Comment: U can give me a example about how to send this key/value with .load()?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because you are not passing the posted value from the `py` file.

try this:

`@app.route('/Items', methods=['POST','GET'])
 def Items():
    item = request.form["value_posted_here"] if "value_posted_here" in request.form else ""
    return render_template("Items.html", nomeUsuario = item)`

then html:

```
<button type="submit" id="formbtn" name="nomeUsuario" value="{{ x[1] }}">Carregar</button>

<script>
    var nomeUsuario = $(this).val();
    $('#formbtn').on('click',function(){
        $("#menu").load('/Items',{'value_posted_here': nomeUsuario });
    }); 
</script>
```